# Is it safe to re-register a drop-target by calling COleDropTarget::Register after COleDropTarget::Revoke?

Tags: winapi, drag-and-drop, ole

As per title really... if I want to temporarily disable drag'n'drop on a dialog with multiple `COleDropTarget` objects registered, can I call `Revoke()` on each object and then `Register()` to re-enable the functionality? Or would I have to destroy and create new `COleDropTarget` objects each time? I cannot see any clue in the MSDN documentation either for this class or the related `RegisterDragDrop` & `RevokeDragDrop` WinAPI functions.

I'll test it, but some assurance it's supposed to be safe to do this repeatedly would be better than "it seems to work".

Answer (score 0):

I don't see why it would be unsafe but this isn't something that's discussed in any documentation so getting an ironclad guarantee is going to be difficult. If you're really worried, why not just make your `IDropTarget::DragEnter` method return `DROPEFFECT_NONE` when you want D&D to be disabled?

Comment: Because that involves adding code in more than one place and relies on future code doing the same thing, rather than have the dialog take 'ownership'.